# How to add SVG angularjs tags inside a custom directive?

Tags: angularjs, svg

I want to make a xy plot of rectangles of different colors based on data. X is days and Y is hours of the day. Its an activity graph.

index.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("app",[]);
        app.controller("controller",function($scope){

        });
        app.directive("graph",function(){
            return {
                controller:function($scope){
                    $scope.val=50;
                },
                templateUrl:"test.html",
                scope:{
                    code:"="
                },
                restrict:"E"
            }
        });
    </script>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
        <graph></graph>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

test.html

```
<svg>  
    <rect x="0" x="0" ng-attr-width="{{val}}" ngheight="50"></rect>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a example of a simple directive that would be replaced with svg:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('graph', function(){
  return {
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      data: '='
    },
    template: '<svg><g><rect ng-repeat="item in data" x="{{item.x}}" y="{{item.y}}" width="{{item.width}}" height="{{item.height}}"></rect></g></svg>'
  };
});
```

That would be used as in [following plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SGB598jEToAa6b27bx6Y?p=preview).

Note however that:

1. You'll get bunch of errors when the DOM is parsed since `{{item.x}}` is not a valid value for `x` attribute until the expression is evaluated by angular. You can overcome this by defining custom `graph-x`, `graph-y`, `graph-*` directives that would apply evaluated values to DOM. More details can be found in this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1050).
2. If you would like to do something more complex I suggest looking into a great library [**D3.js**](http://d3js.org/) which is like `jQuery` for data visualisation in svg.

Comment: ty @miensol for your reply. i tried from scratch and it worked! documentation was there on angularjs.org. ng-attr-x worked! [screenshot](http://pic.twitter.com/Un2x7bg6rq)